# Redirecting on special characters in URL - RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to remove special characters from a URL. In case these special characters are present, I need to redirect to a custom error page.

The rules I have in my `htaccess` file are:

```
RewriteEngine on
    # Rewrite condition: The URL must redirect to a 403 error if the URL contains any special characters (!@$%^&*()_+|~`{}\[\]";'<>,.\/)
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.+_{}~\[\]\(\);,@\!\'\s&$\^)$ [NC]  # Characters like :"|<>*% cannot be disallowed?
    RewriteRule .* - [F,S,L]

    #Error page handeller
    ErrorDocument 400 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 401 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 501 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
    ErrorDocument 502 /example/errordocs/error-code.php
```

I am not able to redirect on the following special characters: `*|"<>`

How do I write the `RewriteCond` statement above so that the request redirects properly? As of now, if the URL contains any of these characters: `*|"<>`, it is redirected to the default error page that comes pre-loaded with `Apache`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to block all the URLs with those chars:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [_{}~\[\]();,@!'&$^<>"|*]|%3C|%3E|%22|%27
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

You can add more characters in this character class `[...]` that you want to block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The above does not work for any except `{}`. I am using `Apache version 2.4 and PHP version 5.4.27`

Comment: @hjpotter92: Like how? If I encode `|` with `%7C`, I still get the same response.

Comment: @Sriram: Try my updated answer. Some characters are encoded directly in the browser itself.

Comment: @anubhava: Tried it. Still does not work. Oddly, apart from `{}` none of the other special characters from the above line work.

Comment: Don't know how you're testing because on my Apache it gets blocked using a curl command line and also using a browser. What is **exact URL** did you use to test it? Also make sure this is very first rule.

Comment: The URL : localhost/example/jshfdjhjf<. This redirects me to the default 403 error page as given in: apache/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var. This is the first and only rule.

Comment: Isn't that correct behavior as we are using `F` flag that will cause 403 and then your `ErrorDocument 403 /example/errordocs/error-code.php` will trigger. What other behavior did you expect?